# Stop the video in UIWebview temporarily in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have seen most of the posts in stackoverflow on how to stop the video from playing.

The solution was to for example,

```
[YourWebView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
```

But in my case, i want to stop it temporarily. This is because when I click another button in the view, I would like the video to stop and when I click the button again, I would like the video to start again. The button for example, shows a alertview.

Any idea how to go about doing this? Need some guidance on this.

EDIT:

This is how I am getting video from Documents Directory to play a video:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[web setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[web loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Why don't you use `MPMoviePlayerController` ?

Comment: used MPMoviePlayerController..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by injecting a script to pause a video by method. `UIWebView`'s

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

NSString *script = @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); videos[i].currentTime = 0;};";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

This will loop through all the video that are in `UIWebView` and pause them.

Comment: whether you are embedding youtube video

Comment: can you make videos[i].currentTime = -1; and check